# Converting special characters with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using a PowerShell script to batch convert Unicode characters to PNG files. See http://pastebin.com/aGJzk4Hh.

I was able to figure out that to convert the `"`  character one must use the designation label:`\"`.

The other special characters are not so simple.

```
C:\ImageMagick\convert.exe -background transparent -fill hsb(0,0,0) \
    -font Arial -pointsize 18 -size 18x26 -gravity center label:"@" \
     C:\Users\erics_000\Desktop\Output\Chars\40.png

convert.exe: UnableToAccessPath  @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3330.
convert.exe: NoImagesDefined `C:\Users\erics_000\Desktop\Output\Chars\40.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

as well as:

```
C:\ImageMagick\convert.exe -background transparent -fill hsb(0,0,0) \
    -font Arial -pointsize 18 -size 18x26 -gravity center label:"\" \
     C:\Users\erics_000\Desktop\Output\Chars\5C.png

convert.exe: NoImagesDefined `label:" C:\Users\erics_000\Desktop\Output\Chars\5C.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

have been very problematic for me.

I have tried every way I know how to escape those characters by way of `\`  however nothing yet has proven to work. I will need to be able to convert all Unicode characters, `\` and `@` included.

Is it known how these can be converted to PNG files with ImageMagick?

Comment: You should start with replacing `label:"\"` by `label:" \ "` (note the added blanks!). Also replace `label:"@"` by `label:" @ "`

Comment: Yes that would work. I think in the case of my script the best solution would be to use the @ to designate a file with a single Unicode character inside. I'm just now finding out what the @ means as I posted to the ImageMagick developer forum. Another comment I posted below on your answer. Your solution works however it is going to lead to a wider image and that may not be what I want to have happen as I intend to use the output for texture mapped text in OpenGL ES. Thank you for  posting it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1st question:** Did you check that your version of Arial does include glyphs for the Unicode characters in question?

Ok, if it is also about the `\` and `@` characters, then *that* shouldn't pose a problem. This leads me to the...

**2nd question:** Which version of ImageMagick do you have installed? Can you report the result of `convert -version`?

Here is *my* result with ImageMagick v6.9.0-0 on a Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9 system:

```
convert -background black -fill red -pointsize 96 label:' @ \\ @ \\ @ ' sample.png
```

[image: sample using '@' and <code>\</code>]

and (note the blanks starting and ending my string!):

```
convert -background transparent -fill hsb\(0,0,0\) -font Arial \
        -pointsize 180 -size 190x210 -gravity center label:' @ ' \
        -frame 1 \
         sample2.png
```

[image]

If you need to emit real Unicode glyphs from an input consisting of Unicode character codes, you can do this with the help of Perl. I guess that Powershell has also a method for this, but I'm not familiar with it):

```
perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); \
      print " Smiley: \x{263A} "'  \
     | convert -background black   \
               -fill red           \
               -pointsize 98       \
               -font Menlo         \
                label:@-           \
                smiley.png
```

(Note: the `@-` syntax just tells convert to read input string for the label from standard input...)

[image: smiley.png]

Comment: I like your answer and I voted. I think in my case the answer is probably to put the character to be converted in a file and use the parameter label:@mychartoconver.txt. I have not tried yet but that's what the developers in the ImageMagick forum are saying. In your example you are converting a string of multiple characters and I am converting a single character. They tell me the @ in the case of the label: parameter is to designate a file and can't be used to designate the @ unicode character.

Comment: If the gravity center truly centers the whole string and clips the excess to the specified image size then your way is very good and I should probably accept your way as the answer but there is also an alternative I just found out about that I have talked about in my other comments.

Comment: I think the proper thing is to link to this then:http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=28021&view=unread&sid=8a8dfa72940017c4562bc69bb5286b42#unread and mark the answer